# pip install -r requirement.txt on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I want to practice how to deploy my code from my mac to my ubuntu (virtualbox)

I have a requirement.txt like this:

```
Django==1.6.4
Fabric==1.8.3
FormEncode==1.2.6
Pillow==2.4.0
SQLAlchemy==0.9.4
SQLObject==1.6.0
Scrapy==0.22.2
South==0.8.4
Tempita==0.5.2
Twisted==13.2.0
argparse==1.2.1
cffi==0.8.2
cryptography==0.3
cssselect==0.9.1
decorator==3.4.0
django-mongodb-engine==0.5.1
djangotoolbox==1.6.2
ecdsa==0.11
fexpect==0.2.post17
lxml==3.3.4
......
```

When I use `sudo pip install -r requirement.txt` in my virtualenv
There is error below:

```
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/cryptography
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
return command.main(cmd_args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And I ckeck `pip freeze`  There is nothing being intalled in requirement.txt

Can someone tell me how to do next? Does it mean that I have to install them one by one?

Comment: First of all, don't do `sudo pip install -r` in your virtualenvironment. The problem here is your file is not encoded correctly, how did you create it on your mac?

Comment: the traceback indicates that your virtual environment is not activated. Drop `sudo`. `which pip` should *not* return `/usr/bin/pip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing `lxml` normally requires a few extra bits and pieces.

try:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

before:

```
pip install lxml
```

**Update:**
Removed `python-dev` from installation

Comment: python-dev should not be required